# Arbitrary sections in a dvi file

Tags: dvi, specials

I'm writing a rendering program that as a part of it will allow the user to render TeX strings.  I was planning on converting the tex string to a dvi and then rendering the dvi myself.  I want the user to be able to write the string in small "sections", of sorts, which can be manipulated in the program, so I was looking into a way to specify these sections in the dvi file.  It seems that the `\special` command is exactly what I'm looking for: I can add a `\special` command before each section giving each section a label, and then I can look for these labels in the dvi file.  For example, writing `\special{section1}Hello, \special{section2}world!` says that the string "Hello," is section 1, and the string "world!" is section 2.  This is the order of things in the dvi file:

- The "section1" special command
- The string "Hello,"
- The "section2" special command
- The string "world!".

This order allows you to determine which letters are in which section.

However, things get messy with subscripts and superscripts.  If I write `\special{section1} e_1 ^{\special{section2} 2}`, this is the order of things in the dvi file:

- The "section1" special command
- The letter "e"
- The "section2" special command (!)
- The letter "2"
- The letter "1"

I want the letters "e" and "1" to be in the same section with "2" in a different section, but instead "2" and "1" are in the same section.

My fundamental question is whether or not there is any way to achieve my initial goal of being able to split strings into arbitrary sections like this.  The end result I want is for the user to be able to say things like "Take '[arbitrary string 1][arbitrary string 2] and treat '[arbitrary string 1]' and '[arbitrary string 2]' differently."  The `\special` mechanism sounds like the way I want to do this, so I initially was thinking that my question would be about it, but I recognize that this could be an XY problem so if something else works I'm fine with using that too.

Also, I understand that there may be more exotic situations like tables where this whole idea of small sections doesn't even make sense, but rendering complicated things like tables as a tex string is not how my program is intended to be used, and I'm fine with saying that things like that are just not supported.  In every situation that this feature will be used, it's obvious to the user what should be colored what.

One thing to note is that I did think about abusing the `xcolor` package by coloring each section differently and then ignoring the color when actually rendering, but it has the same issue.  Writing `\color{red} e_1 ^{\color{blue} 2}` produces a blue 1.

Comment: AFAIK TeX always writes the superscript before the subscript. Instead of *tagging* only the start of a *group* I would suggest to tag the start and end: `\special{start:section1} e_1^{\special{start:section2}2\special{end:section2}}\special{end:section1}`. Now you can process the whole `section1` inclusive `section2`, but also cut off `section2` from `section1` before processing `section1`. For coloring I would recommend to use `\textcolor` and `\mathcolor` instead of `\color`. Otherwise you would need extra groups.

Comment: using color wouldn't change a thing, as colors are using special too, eg `\special{color push rgb 1 0 0}`

Comment: Not an answer, but one step earlier than the DVI file is the output lists that TeX generates, which you can see with `\tracingoutput=1`, for example try the tex file 

`$\special{section1}e_1 ^{\special{section2} 2}$
\tracingonline=1
\showboxbreadth=\maxdimen
\showboxdepth=\maxdimen
\tracingoutput=1
\bye` to see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2gQv.png). AFAIK things are written to the DVI file in the order they are found in the output lists, so you're trying to affect the output lists themselves.